# Python, two dimensional list and coordinates

Tags: python, list, coordinates

I have a two dimensional list:

```
def list():
    list1 =[1,2,3,4,5]
    list2 =[0,0,0,0,0]
    list3 =[6,7,8,9,10]

    list=[list1,list2,list3]

    for i in list:
        print(i)

list()
```

6 will have the coordinates (0,2), right??
I want to move 6 to (0,1) and when I do that, I also want (0,2) to become 0.

How do I do that? I have no idea.. I'm a beginner at this.

Comment: Don't use `list()` as a function or local variable name. You are masking the built-in now.

Comment: You have nested lists, not a two-dimensional list.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign directly to those two index pairs, indexing from the outer list to the inner (the last list is `2`, the middle list is `1`), so the first element of the last list is at `[2][0]`:

```
outerlist[1][0], outerlist[2][0] = outerlist[2][0], 0
```

This assigns two values (one taken from `outerlist[0][2]`, the other the literal `0` integer) to the two positions in the nested lists.

If you wanted to *swap* those two positions (taking the `0` from `outerlist[0][1]`), then do so with the same syntax:

```
outerlist[1][0], outerlist[2][0] = outerlist[2][0], outerlist[1][0]
```

because the right-hand side expression is evaluated before assigning the two values to the left-hand side targets:

```
>>> outerlist = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
>>> outerlist
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
>>> outerlist[1][0], outerlist[2][0] = outerlist[2][0], outerlist[1][0]
>>> outerlist
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```